# HANA SQL Select Count (*) from multiple tables found in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, hana, sql-scripts

```
DECLARE VI_CNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE VI_IDX INTEGER;
DECLARE VI_LIMIT INTEGER;
DECLARE VS_OUTPUTSTRG1 NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE VS_OUTPUTSTRG2 NVARCHAR(500);


/* ANAGRAFICA TABELLE FLUSSI  */

ANAGRAFICA = SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
                               ZCSOURSYS,
                               ZTABLE,
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZCSOURSYS) AS ROW_NB
                            FROM ZDAFNE_INFO);
                                                        

/************ FOR ***********/

SELECT COUNT (ZTABLE) INTO VI_LIMIT FROM :ANAGRAFICA;

FOR VI_IDX IN 1..:VI_LIMIT DO
VI_CNT = :VI_IDX;
SELECT ZTABLE INTO VS_OUTPUTSTRG1 FROM :ANAGRAFICA WHERE ROW_NB = VI_IDX;        
END FOR;

VS_OUTPUTSTRG2 := 'INSERT INTO "TEAMBW"."IFRS17.INTEGRATION.DATA_QUALITY::ZTB_DQ_DAFNE_TEST" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||:VS_OUTPUTSTRG1||'';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (:VS_OUTPUTSTRG2);
```

Hello everyone! Thanks in advance!
Any help about this? The output doesn't insert anything... maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What DBMS is this question related to? The code looks like it is meant for SAP HANA but the question has tags for mysql and postgresql, too.

Comment: Your insert have no commit after it, but you went a wrong way. Lars gave you an answer on how to obtain count in HANA (it is a specific, count is persisted in metadata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the OP wants to store the *raw* record count of a list of tables into yet another table.

This requirement can be met without the use of SQLScript.

SAP HANA keeps the number of committed records in tables available in **catalog tables** like `[M_TABLES][1]`.

With this information available, the `INSERT`-statement can be rewritten like so:

```
INSERT INTO 
     "TEAMBW"."IFRS17.INTEGRATION.DATA_QUALITY::ZTB_DQ_DAFNE_TEST" 
       (TABLE_NAME, RECORD_COUNT)
(SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME, RECORD_COUNT
 FROM M_TABLES
 WHERE 
   SCHEMA_NAME ='xyz' 
   AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
                      FROM ZDAFNE_INFO)
 );
```

This solution works as long as no filtering of to-be-counted records in the source tables is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've thought about this solution already before posting. The fact is that the count shouldn't be done on the whole table, but grouped by "ID_FILE".

Inside the TABLE_NAME, I have millions of records, but the correct information is to get ID_FILE  and RECORD_COUNT. Thats why I thought about the dynamic SQL.

Comment: So, you asked for one thing, got an answer but wanted to know something different, that does not relate to the code provided in the original question.

Comment: I probably didn't explain correctly. Thanks anyway!